# How can I remove one of the two Ubuntu operating systems from my computer?

Tags: grub2, 14.04

Currently I have two Ubuntu 14.04 OSs installed on my computer, and I want to remove one of them. How can I do that? Please explain it to me in detail. I do not want to save the data of unwanted OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is simply delete your partition (of unwanted OS) and then execute `sudo update-grub2` to renew the GRUB from the remaining Ubuntu OS. But, I never doing that, so, waiting for longer (better and proofed) answer.

Comment: Delete unwanted os partition and repair grub with grub-repair with live USB. or try using os-uninstaller.